# How can I insert into a different table using EF based on an object's type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a block of code that inserts a record into the database using EF. I would like to use this same code for inserting into 5 different tables. The only difference is the table name and a single column name. How can I structure the code block so that I insert into the correct table based on an object type?

Current code block:

```
if (entity is Fruit)
{
    FruitLink link = new FruitLink()
    {
       FruitLinkId = // some number,
       // Other properties
    }
    context.FruitLinks.Add(link);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My goal is not to have an `if( entity is Fruit )` statement for each different type I want to insert. The only thing that will change based on the entity type is the table name (ie. FruitLink) and the primary key name (ie. FruitLinkId).

Comment: You may want to research "generic repository pattern with entity framework".  http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/

Comment: Table Per Concrete (TPC) Mappings is your solution, Did my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generic Repository :**

```
public class EFRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext _context;        

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        this._context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    public bool Commit()
    {
        return this._context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
}
```

**Domain Models :**

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public string BaseEntityProp1 { get; set; }
    public string BaseEntityProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1 : BaseEntity
{
    public int Entity1ID { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2 : BaseEntity
{
    public int Entity2ID { get; set; }
}
```

**Table Per Concrete (TPC) Mappings :**

```
public class Entity1Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity1>
{
    public Entity1Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Entity1ID);

        this.Property(e => e.Entity1ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Entity1");
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
    }
}

public class Entity2Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity2>
{
    public Entity2Map()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Entity2ID);

        this.Property(e=> e.Entity2ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Entity2");
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
    }
}
```

**Context :**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{        
    public MyContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Entity1> Entities1{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity1Map());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity2Map());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Sample Data :**

```
EFRepository<BaseEntity> baseRepository = new EFRepository<BaseEntity>(new MyContext ());

List<BaseEntity> entities = new List<BaseEntity>()
{
    new Entity1()
    {
        BaseEntityProp1 = "Entity1Prop1",
        BaseEntityProp2 = "Entity1Prop2",
    },
    new Entity2()
    {
        BaseEntityProp1 = "Entity2Prop1",
        BaseEntityProp2 = "Entity2Prop2",
    }
};

foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    baseRepository.Insert(entity);
    baseRepository.Commit();
}
```